# Rails many to many relations with has many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the following models using the has_many :through relationship.

A recipe can have many seasons.
A season can have many recipes.

Recipe

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name

  has_many :recipe_seasons
  has_many :seasons, through: :recipe_seasons
end
```

Season

```
class Season < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipe_seasons
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_seasons
end
```

Recipe Season

```
class RecipeSeason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :season
end
```

I'm currently displaying all recipes on the index page using the the following

Controller

```
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
    render index: @recipes, include: [:recipe_seasons, :seasons]
  end
```

View

```
 <% if @recipes.present? %>
   <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
     <%= link_to recipe.name,[recipe] %>
 <% end %>
```

What I want to do is to have the seasons displayed with the each recipe. A recipe can have more than one season and so I added another for loop inside the existing one for recipes.

I have so far tried:

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <% recipe.seasons.each do |season| %>
    <%= link_to recipe.name,[recipe] %>
      <%= season.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Current Behaviour**

Recipe 1 - Season 1

Recipe 1 - Season 2

**Expected Behaviour**

Recipe 1 - Season 1, Season 2

Recipe 2 - Season 4

Comment: what happens if you change your code to print the recipe.name first and only then iterate over the seasons of each recipe and print the season name? Also, in the rails console, what is the output of "recipe.seasons" for a recipe with many seasons? Does it show the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You must include the seasons in the `body` parameter of the [`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) (the text displayed in the link)

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
   <%= link_to "#{recipe.name} - #{recipe.seasons.map(&:name).join(', ')}", [recipe] %>
<% end %>
```